# How does a C program take command line arguments at run time?

Tags: c

I know that C programs can be passed arguments externally (from the command line) like

```
gcc.exe -std=c++17 -o fileName
```

by declaring function `main` as taking parameters

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

My question is, where are these strings stored? In C, isn't the size of an array supposed to be known at compile-time. You could pass many, many arguments (strings) to the program, or none at all. But the program has already been compiled into an executable - it can't take more or less memory than it already does. Or is this memory allocated dymamically?

Comment: Note: `[]` in an argument is basically a pointer, so the size is not known. That's what `argc` is for.

Comment: Not just "basically".  Where used for C function parameters, the declarations `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` and even `char *argv[17]` all mean *exactly* the same thing.  Of course, the same is not true when such declarations appear at block or file scope.

Answer (score 5):

On DOS, the strings are stored at __psp:128 (__psp is usually DS but need not be).

On Windows, the strings are stored on the heap. The original command line is stored in a memory slab with a really low address.

On Linux, the strings are stored on the bottom of the stack.

Comment: But isn't the amount of stack memory to be used by a program known at compile-time?

Comment: @NasratTakoor: No. Consider the recursive function (function that conditionally calls itself). Also C allows dynamically sized arrays to be declared on the stack (but not at global scope).

Comment: @Joshua, on the top of the stack (the stack normally grows downwards in address space, so they are at the top address --- but the stack top is effectively below, as you say at the bottom) what a mess!!!! :)

Comment: @LuisColorado: I usually pick up which the writer thinks is which from context. Though I did see some nutcase use the free end of the stack for locals before.

Answer (score 2):

The language definition itself only says this:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> 2    If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
> constraints:
>      — The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
>      — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>      — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
> `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
> implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. **The
> intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
> from elsewhere in the hosted environment.** If the host environment is not capable of
> supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
> shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
>      — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
> represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
> program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
> greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
> represent the program parameters.
>      — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
> be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
> startup and program termination.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Which is basically a long-winded way of saying - it's up to the implementation.  The strings come from the host environment, they're stored in such a way that they are modifiable, and they exist over the lifetime of the program.  They're set up as the program is loaded into memory, in many cases probably taking a chunk of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in unix operating systems, the values for the strings that compose the array `argv` and the array of pointers, and the value for `argc` are initializing the first stack frame in the stack.  Just above the first return value, to make `main()` to work as a normal C function.  This is handled normally by the `exec(2)` system call, in the majority of unices (including linux, bsd systems, solaris, and possibly more)

The official answer, although is that this is implementation dependent, so you cannot assume anything about where or how they are stored in the program  virtual space.